# Copiar registro actual de una tabla a otra por php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando poder copiar 1 registro de una tabla a otra mediante php. Quiero que al marcar el checkbox y envie el formulario me copie el registro. El código que tengo no me da error pero tampoco me copia. A ver si alguien ve donde me esta fallando:

```
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="conditions" name="conditions" 
                 value="1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="conditions">Dar de Baja</label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sendForm" value="Enviar"/>
                </form>

                <?php

                $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gestcof_bd");

                /* verificar conexion */
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Error enconexión: ". mysqli_connect_error();
                exit();
                }


                if (isset($_POST['sendForm'])) {
                if (isset($_POST['conditions']) && $_POST['conditions'] == '1')
                $hermano = $_POST['id_hermano'];
                $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO bajas SELECT * FROM hermanos WHERE 
                                    'id_hermano'=$hermano");
                $mysqli->close();
               } else{
                 echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Marcar casilla para copiar.</div>';
                }
                ?>
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Vi que me faltan un par de parentesis en la query sql ya los puse pero sigue sin copiar nada. Tambien me fije y las dos tablas son estructuralemnte identicas.

Answer (score 0):

tu formulario no esta enviando `id_hermano` deberias incluir un input de la siguiente manera:`<input type="text" id="id_hermano" name="id_hermano" value="valor_requerido_db" />`